# How to print page exactly it looks on screen using window.print()?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have designed a form for my project and I want to print the form. The form looks like below:
[image: Actual Form]

I was trying to use window.print() method to print it. But it changed the style in print preview like below: [image: print preview]

Here's my code that I've done. Let me know if there any possible way to solve this issue and print exactly it shown in the window. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Registrationform.css">
</head>
<body>



<div style="width:670px; padding:30px; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888888;" class="container">
        <table style="margin: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td><img width="60px" height="60px" src="images\NSTU-logo.png"></td>
                <td>
                <div class = "header-name">
                <h6 style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">NOAKHALI SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY UNIVERSITY</h6>
                <p style="text-align: center; margin:auto;">Noakhali-3814, Bangladesh</p>
                <h6 style="text-align: center;margin: auto;">COURSE REGISTRATION FORM</h6>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        

    
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <!-- <div style=" align-content: center;" class = "std-header-info"> -->
                 <div>
                     <label>Name</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 365px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'name' placeholder="" value="Khair" readonly>
                     <label>Roll</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 160px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'roll' placeholder="" value="12" readonly> <br>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                    <label>Department</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 230px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'department' placeholder="" value="IIT" readonly>
                     <label>Institute/Faculty</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 165px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'institute' placeholder="" value="IIT" readonly>
                     <br/>
                 </div>

                 <div>
                     <label>Year</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 120px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'year' placeholder="" value="2012" readonly>
                     <input type="hidden" name="year" value="" />

                     <label>Term</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 150px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'term' placeholder="" value="2" readonly>

                     <label>Session</label>
                     <input class="text" style = "width: 200px; text-align: center;" type="text" id = 'session' placeholder="" value="2017" readonly>
                 </div>
                 <br/>


            


                 <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Course Code</th>
                                <th>Course Title</th>
                                <th>Credits</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </div>
                 
                 <div>
                     <table style="font-size: 10px;" class="table table-bordered" id="table">
                        <tr class="borderless">
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                            <td colspan="2">Year 1</td>
                            <td colspan="2">Year 2</td>
                            <td colspan="2">Year 3</td>
                            <td colspan="2">Year 4</td>
                            <td colspan="2">Year 5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="font-size: 8px">
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                            <td>Term-I</td>
                            <td>Term-II</td>
                            <td>Term-I</td>
                            <td>Term-II</td>
                            <td>Term-I</td>
                            <td>Term-II</td>
                            <td>Term-I</td>
                            <td>Term-II</td>
                            <td>Term-I</td>
                            <td>Term-II</td>
                        </tr>
                     
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">Credit <br> Completed </td> 
                            
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">GPA</td>
                            <td>3.23</td>
                            <td>3.21</td>
                            <td>3.43</td>
                            <td>3.52</td>
                            <td>3.12</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>

                        </tr>

                     </table>
                 </div>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.print()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using pixel (px) , please use percentage for the table / div / cell widths

Comment: If this were CSS you had written yourself, I would suggest looking for @media queries that do not select the print mode. Bootstrap seems to be doing that for you. The main issue here, however, is the absolute sizes (px). You need to use relative units to prevent the page behaving unusually on different screen sizes. Percentages (n%) and root element relative units (nrem) are good for this purpose.

Comment: In this case, Sometimes Bootstrap CDN will not work properly. Try with download Bootstrap locally.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited the first few parts of lines and it's fine now. But bootstrap tables background white color irritating me.

Comment: Bootstrap is causing an issue here. Bootstrap CDN has this issue with width. In this case, you might use `@media-queries`. And try to use `%` rather than `px`.

Comment: I think it's scaling issue, (that's a guess), `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` add this line in you head tag to scale your website for all screen size.